# Codeigniter file_put_contents: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, codeigniter

While Uploading the image in the server I got the error in codeigniter. But it works fine in local system.

A PHP Error was encountered:

```
Severity: Warning

Message: file_put_contents(upload/logo/1617000545.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Filename: models/Logo_m.php
```

Line Number: 41

`````
    list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
        list(, $data) = explode(',', $data);
       
        $data = base64_decode($data);
        $imageName = time().'.png';

        file_put_contents('upload/logo/'.$imageName, $data);````
`````

Comment: I assume the server is a linux server? Please check if the `upload/logo/` directory exists on the server with proper permissions. If the directory already exists, then the webserver user that is running the CodeIgniter application, probably does not have write permission in the said directory.

Comment: Its window's server. Now I get it. Its due to permission issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have check about your directory or permission?

Some problem maybe cause:

1. Directory Does not exists, you must create it first.
2. Permissions / Script does not have enough access to write files, you must verify the application could write directory and directory is writable.

Your code also doesn't validate the image content / metadata;

```
// $data = trim(explode(',', explode(';', $data)[1])[1]);
list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data) = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
// determine absolute path
$imageDirectory = __DIR__ .'/upload/logo';
// check if string / content is an image
if (! ($imgInfo = getimagesizefromstring($data))) {
    // do exit here because data is not a binary image string
    throw new Exception('Data is not an image');
}
// check if image directory exist
if (!file_exists($imageDirectory)) {
    mkdir($imageDirectory, 755, true);
}
if (!is_dir($imageDirectory) || !is_writable($imageDirectory)) {
    throw new Exception('Could not save image. Directory is not writable.');
}

$extension = $imgInfo['mime'];
// optional to filter jpeg image
if ($extension  === 'jpeg') {
    $extension = 'jpg';
}
// use only time is not recommended due time is not unique, please change with random value
$baseName = time();
$imageName = $baseName . '.' . $extension;
$written   = file_put_contents($imageDirectory.'/'.$imageName, $data);
```

Comment: Thank you, Its due to the permission error for that directory. I resolved it.